# SQL Server Auto increment key primary key while mering new values into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm editing a SQL server stored proc at work, and currently it uses a cursor and the @@Identity to do the following. I'm trying to move to a more set based approach.

From what I gather I am trying to merge a temporary table (the new information) to the current table (old information) In no particular order I need to do something like the following.
 - Create new rows
 - Create new PrimaryKeys
 - Duplicate old information (aside from PrimaryKey) into new rows.
 - Alter two of the old columns to the "new" information.

The problem I "think" I'm having is how to create new primaryKey values for all of these rows. -> How do I get the "highest" old primary key value that is in the database?

So; here is somewhat fake looking SQL Code.

```
Merge Target as T
Using @TemporaryTable as S --Source
on T.vPrimaryID = S.vPrimaryID
AND T.Arbitary = S.Arbitrary --Arbitrary business rule, shouldn't matter
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
PrimaryKey = newPrimaryKey -- This is where I'm having problems 
Col2 = S.col2
Col3 = T.col3
Col4 = T.col4
Col5 = GetDate() --new Timestamp
```

The database is set up with "versioning" the primaryKey is the "version" so it should be primary, unique and not null.

For full disclosure after running this I need the TARGET table to update its previous matched rows and set a boolean flag from true to false. (Basically a soft delete)
That part I'm not too worried about at the moment.

Any ideas how that primaryKey will work? I feel like I'm missing something conceptually.
I am using MS-SQL Server. I am unable to provide the old proc or real code due to IP policy at my work.

Comment: Is PrimaryKey _really_ the primary key, i.e. something that you can't change? You can use an `OUTPUT` clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. `Id` values.  `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both before and after values in the case of `UPDATE`.  A tool well worth having in your pocket. And avoid @@IDENTITY.

Comment: After getting the output; how would I increment? I feel like I could do something like the following. SELECT TOP 1 PrimaryKey FROM Source ORDER BY PrimaryKey DESC

Comment: You may be right, I don't know if the PrimaryKey... is the PrimaryKey and if an actual constraint is in place;but due to our versioning strategy I need to keep that old row intact and increment it by one. How would I check if it really is a primaryKey in MS SQL?

Comment: I'm not sure you're using the phrase Primary Key properly.

Comment: @Zane I was being pretty loose with it. Isn't a primary key a non-null, distinct/unique value that serves to find the rest of the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since last person who created a a stored procedure and used `@@IDENTITY` function in the procedure I take it its an IDENTITY Column (Auto Increment), You do not need to provide any value for it when inserting New Rows, It generates the next available value for you.

The code you have shown in your question it is not at all `fake SQL Code`, It is a proper legit `MERGE STATEMENT`, Used when you want to do multiple Operation in one SQL Statement (DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT).

Not having all the information about Table Variable used in this show example. Since you have mentioned you want to add new rows to your data.

You can simply add another condition in your merge statement to add the rows which does not exist in your target table. and it is already updating rows that already exist.

You can do something like this ....

```
Merge Target as T
Using(SELECT * FROM @TemporaryTable) as S   --Source
on T.vPrimaryID = S.vPrimaryID
AND T.Arbitary = S.Arbitrary --Arbitrary business rule, shouldn't matter
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
                      -- For Primary key its an Identity column it will 
T.Col2 = S.col2         -- generate the new values for you 
T.Col3 = S.col3
T.Col4 = S.col4
T.Col5 = GetDate() 

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
 INSERT (T.Col2,T.Col3,T.Col4,T.Col5,....)  -- Do not use the Identity column here 
  VALUES (S.Col2,S.Col3,S.Col4,S.Col5,....)  -- it will be auto generated for you
```

Comment: I wasn't able to implement this at work due to the project being stashed (requires complex business rules/spec sheet); but you did clear it up for me and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Not a problem, atleast next time when you see a `MERGE STATEMENT` you will know its a legit sql code not fake sql :)

Comment: I made that sql myself; I just doing it as a conceptual exercise in pseudo code. I knew it was "real-ish" surprised it was totally legit. My job uses cursors frequently and merge statements very, very rarely.

Comment: `CURSORS` ouch....  try avoiding cursors as much as possible. I think there is hardly any situation where you have to use cursor, otherwise Temp table, CTE and ranking functions has made almost everything possible without using cursors.